# Cloning/Copying an NSMutableArray in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

How are arrays cloned or copied into other arrays in Objective-C?

I would like to have a function which when passed in an NSMutableArray, it takes the array and fills up  another array with the content.

Is it as simple as someArray = passedInArray? OR os there some initWith function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work good enough

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:myArray];
```

Also, `copy` method probably does the same

```
[myArray copy];
```

But simple assignment won't clone anything. Because you assign only a reference (your parameter probably looks like `NSMutableArray *myArray`, which means `myArray` is a reference).

Comment: Invoking copy on a mutable array will return a new non-mutable array.   Invoke mutableCopy instead if you want another mutable array.

Answer (score 5):

Don't mind but your question seems to be a **duplicate** [deep-copy-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647260/deep-copy-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c); however let me try.

Yeah its not so simple, you have to be somewhat more careful

```
/// will return a reference to myArray, but not a copy
/// removing any object from myArray will also effect the array returned by this function
-(NSMutableArray) cloneArray: (NSMutableArray *) myArray {
    return [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: myArray];
}

/// will clone the myArray
-(NSMutableArray) cloneArray: (NSMutableArray *) myArray {
    return [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: myArray];
}
```

Here is documentation article [Copying Collections](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html)

Comment: do you mean to use initWithArray:copyItems:YES for that second method? As it stands, I believe those two methods are identical.