# Creating new array

Tags: java, arrays

The question is very simple. Is any simple and fast way to create **new** (new references) array or it has to be done manually?

Example:

```
Collection<A> c = new ArrayList<A>();
c.add(new A());
c.add(new A());
c.add(new A());

A[] a1 = c.toArray(new A[0]);
System.out.println("a1: " + Arrays.toString(a1));
System.out.println("c: " + c);

A[] a2 = Arrays.copyOf(a1, a1.length);
System.out.println("a2: " + Arrays.toString(a2));
```

All created arrays has the same references. I want array with new elements with the same content as old elements. Copies of old elements.

Answer is: [How do you make a deep copy of an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java) . Now I see that this question is duplicate.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question: do you mean you want a deep copy instead of a shallow copy?

Comment: Is this a shallow clone (in which just the collection is new) or a deep clone (in which the actual objects in the collection are copied

Comment: If u r looking for deep copy try serialization

Comment: Yes, deep copy. Copy of content, not copy of references.

Comment: Deep copies are expensive.  Generally I write code so I never need to do that.

Comment: Please check if this helps you out: http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/

got from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a *deep* copy of the array (meaning: with freshly created references to each of its elements), there are several alternatives, including:

- Serialize/deserialize the array (see Apache's `SerializationUtils`)
- Manually copying each element (and that element's attributes, recursively)
- Using reflection explicitly
- Using a copy constructor

... And so on. Look in stack overflow, there are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182565/java-deep-copy-shallow-copy-clone) discussing the subject.