# clone() and system.arracopy() of an array creates two arrays with different references in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, clone, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Firstly I have to say this is not a duplicate of `deep copying vs shallow copying (clone)` in Java. but it is related to that. I have read other posts on `deep vs shallow copying` in SO and while working on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182565/java-deep-copy-shallow-copy-clone), I found some problem with my understanding.
Question is : `clone() and system.arraycopy()` gives different arrays in the below example. but they aren't supposed to?

I used array as a field in another example object below. There again I see they are different references for the arrays fields. The code is commented for easy following.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;


class Example {
        public int foo;
        public int[] bar;

        public Example (int foo, int[] bar) {
         this.foo = foo; 
        this.bar = bar; 
        }
        public void setfoo(int foo){
            this.foo=foo;
        }
        public int[] getbar(){
            return bar;
        }
}
public class ClonevsDeepCopy {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Example 1
        StringBuffer[] arr = {new StringBuffer("abc"),new StringBuffer("def"),
                                     new StringBuffer("ghi")};
        StringBuffer[] arr2 = arr.clone();
        StringBuffer[] arr3 = new StringBuffer[3];
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr3, 0, 2);
        //check for identity
        System.out.println(arr==arr2);
        System.out.println(arr==arr3);
        //End of example 1

        //Example 2
        /*this is equivalent of shallow copying which is clone()
         * The normal interpretation is that a "shallow" copy of eg1 
         * would be a new Example object whose foo equals 1 
         * and whose bar field refers to the same array as in the original; e.g.
         */
        Example eg1 = new Example(1, new int[]{1, 2});
        Example eg2 = new Example(eg1.foo,eg1.bar);
        System.out.println(eg1.bar==eg2.bar);
        eg1.setfoo(4);
        eg1.bar[0]=99;

        /*This is equivalent of deep coying
        The normal interpretation of a "deep" copy of eg1 would 
        be a new Example object whose foo equals 
        1 and whose bar field refers to a copy of the original array; e.g.
        */
        Example eg3 = new Example(eg1.foo,Arrays.copyOfRange(eg1.bar, 0, 2));
        System.out.println(eg3.bar==eg1.bar);
        //cloning on array
        Example eg4 = new Example(eg1.foo,eg1.bar.clone());
        System.out.println(eg4.bar==eg1.bar);
        //End of example 2




    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing strange here.

If `arr1` is the result or `arr.clone()` then `arr1!=arr` but `arr1[0]==arr[0]` if it is defined. If `arr1=arr` is the assignment then `arr1==arr`.

#### Details:

We have 5 results:

`false` at `System.out.println(arr==arr2);`:

Nothing strange here, we're comparing the array references themselves, not the contents.

`false` at `System.out.println(arr==arr3);`

Nothing strange, different arrays.

`true` at `System.out.println(eg1.bar==eg2.bar);`:

Nothing strange, same references.

Last two `false`:

Again, we're performing some shallow copies. The elements are still equal references, but the  arrays are different references.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is confusing you. `System.arraycopy()` copies elements from one array to another. It doesn't play with reference.

`Array#clone()` javadoc states

> The general intent is that, for any object x, the expression:
>
> x.clone() != x

Therefore you will get different references.

More detail

```
StringBuffer[] arr = {new StringBuffer("abc"),new StringBuffer("def"),
                                 new StringBuffer("ghi")};
StringBuffer[] arr2 = arr.clone();
StringBuffer[] arr3 = new StringBuffer[3];
```

You have 3 different references. Then, see code comments

```
System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr3, 0, 2); // copy values from arr into arr, the references haven't changed
//check for identity
System.out.println(arr==arr2); // different references
System.out.println(arr==arr3); // different references
```

`Arrays.copyOf()` returns a **new** array (new reference) with values from the source array.

```
Example eg3 = new Example(eg1.foo,Arrays.copyOfRange(eg1.bar, 0, 2));
```

Therefore

```
System.out.println(eg3.bar==eg1.bar);
```

is `false`.

And more

```
   Example eg4 = new Example(eg1.foo,eg1.bar.clone());
   System.out.println(eg4.bar==eg1.bar);
```

`clone()` returns a new reference, so you are again comparing different references and get `false`.

If you're looking to compare the contents of the arrays, use

```
Arrays.equals(arr, arr2); // for example
```

Note that here it doesn't matter because of primitive types, but if your array held reference types, you might care about shallow or deep copies.

Answer (score 0):

Much confusion will be avoided if you regard type `object` and all its derivatives as holding "object identifiers".  A variable of type `StringBuffer` doesn't hold an instance of `StringBuffer`--it holds an object identifier which, if non-blank (i.e. not null), will identify an instance of `StringBuffer`.  Likewise, a variable of type `StringBuffer[]` doesn't hold an array--it holds an object identifier which, if non-blank, will identify an instance of `StringBuffer[]` which, in turn, won't hold instances of `StringBuffer`, but will instead identify them.

When code says `someVariable.someMember=5;`, the code isn't writing to `someVariable`.  Instead, it examines `someVariable`, notices which object it identifies, and then modifies the appropriate field *of that object*.  It may look as though the right-hand part of the statement has something to do with `someVariable`, but it doesn't.  Once the system determines what object is identified by `someVariable`, that variable will be out of the picture.