# Strange array copying error

Tags: java, arrays, copy, java-3d

I am writing a `Java3D` program that draws a 3D graph. I hold the points of the graph in an array and pass it into a `createMesh()` and `createGraph()` function. Here is how I get the points of the graph:

```
    double x=xmin;
    Point3d[] vertices = new Point3d[graph.length*graph[0].length];
    for(int i=0, index=0; i<graph.length; i++, x+=((xmax-xmin)/graph.length))
    {
        double y = ymin;
        for(int j=0; j<graph[i].length; j++, y+=((ymax-ymin)/graph[i].length), index++)
        {
            double z = Math.sin(Math.pow(x, 2)+Math.pow(y, 2))/(Math.pow(x, 2)+Math.pow(y, 2));
            Point3d point = new Point3d(x, z, y);
            if(z>zmax)
                zmax = z;
            if(z<zmin)
                zmin = z;
            vertices[index] = new Point3d(x, z, y);
        }
    }
```

In the `createGraph()` method, I need to set the y-values of the points to 0. To keep the original vertices array unchanged, I copy the array passed to the `createGraph()` method like this:

```
private Shape3D createGraph(Point3d[] tempA)
{
    Point3d[] vertices = (Point3d[])tempA.clone();
    ...
}
```

In the `createMesh()` method, I don't change the values of the vertices array, so I don't copy it. My program first calls `createGraph()` and copies the array and then calls `createMesh()` and reads the original array. The problem is that when I make the mesh using the points in the original vertices array, the y-values of the original array are somehow also 0. I could just call `createMesh()` first, but I still want to figure out whats going on with my program.

Comment: Shallow copy with clone. You need a deep copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is not recommended to use [clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) in Java since [clone is broken](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).

Second, by using clone - you're cloning the array - not the items in the array. For more information in regards read about [deep vs. shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182565/java-deep-copy-shallow-copy-clone).

Comment: To add to that, copy constructors are where it's at. `Point3d[] newarray = new Point3d[original.length]; for(int i=0, last=newarray.length; i<last; i++) { newarray[i] = new Point3d(original[i]); }` hurray, now we've actually made new objects. And are taking up twice the memory.

Comment: I would use a simple for-loop, but sometimes I have over 100,000 points and I know that for larger arrays, deep-copies are better. Otherwise, I would totally do that.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch nope. [Arrays.copyOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)) creates a shallow copy.

Answer (score 1):

Java Object.clone() will pass a reference to the original object if the Object is not a primitive type. You need to to a deep copy.

Following articles will help you.

[A guide to object cloning in java](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/08/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/)

[how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java)

Comment: Oh, I thought clone() would copy _all_ types of values into another variable, not just primitives. Thank You.