# Implementing clone method - Error java: clone() has protected access in java.lang.Object

Tags: java, clone

I am writing this little program but it has a mistake which I can't find.
I have been searching and reading about it on the internet for hours but I keep getting the same error message: java: clone() has protected access in java.lang.Object.
I am trying to implement the method clone() on Point so that after executing Main only c1 does moveTo.
Could someone please tell me what is the problem and how do I solve it?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p = new Point(5,7);
        Circle c1 = new Circle(p, 3);
        Circle c2 = new Circle(p, 5);

        System.out.println("c1 = " + c1);
        System.out.println("c2 = " + c2);

        c1.moveTo(2,3);
        Circle cloned = (Circle) c2.clone();

        System.out.println("c1 = " + c1);
        System.out.println("c2 = " + c2);
    } }

 public class Circle {
     public final Point center;
     public final int radius;

     public Circle(Point center, int radius) {
         this.center = center;
         this.radius = radius;
     }

     public void moveTo(int x, int y){
         center.setX(x);
         center.setY(y);
     }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return "Circle{" +
                 "center=" + center.toString() +
                 ", radius=" + radius +
                 '}';
     } }

public class Point implements Cloneable{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point{" +
                "x=" + x +
                ", y=" + y +
                '}';
    } }
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578517/should-i-use-clone-method-in-java

Answer (score 0):

It is because the line `Circle cloned = (Circle) c2.clone();` You are trying to access a protected member outside of the class it is defined. A protected method can only be called in the same class or a child class.

if you really want to access it in the **Main** class only, Then override the *clone()* method in **Circle** class and make it `public` as well as write your own implementation if needed.

```
class Circle {
    public final Point center;
    public final int radius;

    public Circle( Point center, int radius ) {
        this.center = center;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void moveTo( int x, int y ) {
        center.setX( x );
        center.setY( y );
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // TODO: Your custom clone logic
        return super.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Circle{" +
            "center=" + center.toString() +
            ", radius=" + radius +
            '}';
    }
}
```