# Why can't I copy a value from one XYSeriesCollection to other?

Tags: java, swing, time, histogram, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart to create an image histogram in java swing. In order to create it I iterate over all pixels to get all the colors. Depending on the size and bit depth it takes some time.

Once I have all the data I put it into a XYSeriesCollection variable. To be able to show and hide some series latter I save a copy of that variable.

My problem is that if I do it like this:

```
final XYSeriesCollection data = createHistogram();
final XYSeriesCollection dataCopy = createHistogram();
```

It works without any problem, but it is not efficient, as I have to iterate over all pixels and that takes a while.

If I just copy it like this:

```
final XYSeriesCollection data = createHistogram();
final XYSeriesCollection dataCopy = data;
```

When I execute the code I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Series index out of bounds
at org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection.getSeries(XYSeriesCollection.java:263)
```

I think that this is because when I delete the series from data some how they also get deleted from dataCopy but shouldn't those be completely different? I just work with this methods:

```
data.removeAllseries();
data.addSeries(dataCopy.getSeries(index));
```

For example if I create:

```
int x = 5;
int y = x;
x=0;
System.out.println(y)
```

The output should still be  5 and it doesn't matter what I did with x. What am I doing or assuming that is wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the difference between [*shallow* versus *deep* copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6182565/230513). Your example, `dataCopy = data`, makes a [*shallow*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184710/230513) copy. Use the dataset's `clone()` method to make a [*deep*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184710/230513) copy:

```
XYSeriesCollection dataCopy = (XYSeriesCollection) data.clone();
```

You can see how `clone()` is implemented [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeriesCollection.html#line.449). The fragment below creates a series, clones it, and updates the original to illustrate the effect.

Code:

```
XYSeriesCollection data = new XYSeriesCollection();
XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Test");
data.addSeries(series);
series.add(1, 42);
System.out.println(data.getSeries(0).getY(0));
XYSeriesCollection dataCopy = (XYSeriesCollection) data.clone();
series.updateByIndex(0, 21.0);
System.out.println(data.getSeries(0).getY(0));
System.out.println(dataCopy.getSeries(0).getY(0));
```

Console:

```
42.0
21.0
42.0
```

Also consider the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513), which may be faster.

Comment: Thank's a lot, now works perfectly. I've been trying to do the histogram like that link says but then once I have done it I can't show a single R, G or B channel by removing series from the data collection, as HistogramDataset doesn't contain the method remove series. Therefore I decided to write everything by myself, going through all the pixels, and for a 17Mpx TIFF photo and 16bit per color in a macbook pro 2012 13" it takes around 4 seconds.

Comment: @nck: Instead of altering the model, change the visibility of a series in the view; [`VisibleAction`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513) is an example.