# Set foreground alpha on legend symbol in jFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, alphablending, alpha-transparency

I'm setting the foreground alpha on a jFreeChart and I'd like the color to match the legend symbol. It is possible to also set the Foreground Alpha on the legend symbol as well?

[image]

Code to set the plot alpha:

```
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.6f);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the plot and legend get colors from the plot's [`DrawingSupplier`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/DrawingSupplier.html). To ensure that plot and legend stay synchronized, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40545725/230513) supplies red, green and blue hues each having 50% *alpha*.

```
Paint[] paintArray = {
    new Color(0x80ff0000, true),
    new Color(0x8000ff00, true),
    new Color(0x800000ff, true)
};
plot.setDrawingSupplier(new DefaultDrawingSupplier(
    paintArray, …));
```

Note the subtle difference from having a light gray background in the plot but not the legend.

[image]