# Deep clone with copy constructor and object.clone()

Tags: java, clone, copy-constructor, deep-copy

what is the difference between deep copy of an object with copy constructor and using object.clone() ? Copy constructor is very easy to use but I wonder if there are any limitations. Also what is the difference between deep copy and deep clone ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182565/deep-copy-shallow-copy-clone ?

Comment: One is called by `new Object(instance)` the other is `instance.clone()`. Using a Constructor might simply take some value to build a different instance, clone SHOULD build the exact same instance.