# Swift's struct in Kotlin (or Java)? Multiple instances of the same class, mutating its variables

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, kotlin

I am not sure if I am clear with my title. In Swift I have this struct.

```
struct Movement {
 let name: String
 var reps: Int
}

let movement1 = Movement(name: "Push Ups", reps: 20)

var movementA = movement1
movementA.reps = 30

print(movement1.reps) // Prints 20
print(movementA.reps) // Prints 30
```

What is alternative in Kotlin (or Java)? The problem is that in my app I have a workout that consists of multiple movements. I append these movements to the MutableList and the problem appears when I have workout where a movement is repeated.

For example when I want to enter workout like:

20 Push Ups

30 Pull Ups

40 Push Ups

I end up with:

40 Push Ups

30 Pull Ups

40 Push Ups

At first, I select movement #1 and set reps of movement #1 but when I select movement #3 and set reps of movement #3 it overrides variables of movement #1.

Any idea?

I have tried something like this but it didn't work.

```
class Movement(name: String) {
 var reps: Int? = null
}
val movement1 = Movement("Push Ups")
movement1.reps = 20
var movementA = movement1
movementA.reps = 30
Log.i("REPS1: ", movement1.reps.toString()) // 30
Log.i("REPSA: ", movementA.reps.toString()) // 30
```

Comment: Java has [```Object.clone()```](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()), which works (well, does something) on anything marked [```Cloneable```](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html). But I could not tell how this mechanism appears in Kotlin.

Comment: Why can't you just create a new instance of `Movement` instead of assigning it to another variable?

Comment: Java is a little weird in the way in handles copies, but here's some good SO threads on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182565/deep-copy-shallow-copy-clone and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java

Comment: That is because Class is reference type, whereas Struct is value type in Swift. I have never used Kotlin, though `data class` seems like the Struct for Kotlin from Bubletan's answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have never used Swift, but it seems like you're having a mutable value which gets copied when you assign it to a new variable. In Kotlin, you cannot have such type. When you assign a value to a new variable, only the reference gets copied and it still points to the same exact memory location.

You could use a data class which gives you a convenient copy method:

```
data class Movement(val name: String, val reps: Int)

val movement1 = Movement("Push Ups", 20)
val movementA = movement1.copy(reps = 30)
```

Comment: Using data class + .copy() solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

First, let me cover why you have the same value for both `movement1` and `movementA`. When you assign in Kotlin, you are copying a reference, not a class.

```
var movementA = movement1
```

So what that does is create a new variable called `movementA` and points it to the exact same object that `movement1` is pointing to.

I think you probably want to look at [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html). They come with a copy constructor that might come in handy.

```
data class Movement(val name: String, val reps: Int)
```

And then you can create them off of each other, like in the swift code you show above.

```
val movement1 = Movement("Push-Ups", 20)
val movementA = movement1.copy(reps = 30)
```

Or you could make the properties `var`s instead of `val`s and mutate them directly...

```
data class Movement(var name: String, var reps: Int)
var movement1 = Movement("Push-Ups", 20)
var movementA = movement1.copy()
movementA.reps = 30
```

Comment: Using data class + .copy() solved my problem, thanks!