# Copy attribute of Objective-C property creates a deep copy or a shallow copy?

Tags: objective-c

I have an `NSMutabelArray` with some objects in it as a property of my `View-Controller`.
Now I pass this array when I push this VC.

I initially made it assign.

but now I needed to modify the array whenever the device rotates, in the VC without affecting the one in previous VC.
so made it a copy property.

now I was individually changing the objects in the array.

but somehow..the array in my prev VC was also changing.

I had to create a new `NSMutabelArray` with modified objects and had to set to my property.

Is it that copy attribute just makes another array with same references of objects added to the array ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `copy` attribute means the property will be assigned the object returned after sending the `copy` message to the object that was passed in. Whether that means deep or shallow depends on the object getting copied. The Foundation collections create shallow copies because that allows `copy` to be implemented as `retain` for immutable collections.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it that copy attribute just makes another array with same references of objects added to the array ?

Yes, that's how it works.

There's some suggestions for deep copying an array in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647260/deep-copy-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c). Maybe one of those would work for you?