# Deep Copy and Shallow Copy

Tags: iphone, nsarray

I have read the answer for difference between deep copy and shallow copy from the post, [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) . Now I got some doubt that when we made a shallow copy by

```
 newArray = [NSmutableArray arrayWithArray:oldArray];
```

the new array will point to oldArray. (As from the figure).  Now what happen when I remove object from newArray? As from figure, it should remove same element from oldArray too !!! It seems like

`newArray = oldArray` is a shallow copy and `newArray = [NSmutableArray arrayWithArray:oldArray];` is deep copy. Is it right?

Comment: newArray = oldArray is not a copy at all. It's just a second variable that points at the same array.

Comment: Using `arrayWithArray:`, you have a **new** array referencing the same objects.

Comment: This is a way to copy array deep copy
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/647269/1189448

Comment: I found this good answer to copy real deep copy
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15040786/1189448

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`newArary = oldArray` isn't a copy at all. You end up with two pointers pointing to the exact same memory location.

`newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:oldArray];` is a shallow copy. You end up with two distinct arrays, so if you were to remove or add items from one array, it wouldn't affect the other array. However, the **items** in the two arrays are identical. If the first element of `oldArray` were an `NSMutableDictionary` and you added a key to it, you'd see that change on the first element of `newArray` as well (since those two objects are the same).

To do a deep copy, you would have to make a new array, and each element of the new array would be a deep copy of the corresponding element of the old array. (Yes, that definition is recursive).

Comment: According to Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCopying.html), So if object A is shallow-copied to object B, object B refers to the same instance variable (or property) that object A refers to. Hence newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:oldArray]; is a deep copy not shallow copy. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, `NSArray`'s don't have a deep copy function. However, you can make a deep copy function by doing the following:

```
@interface NSArray(deepCopy)

-(NSArray *) deepCopy;

@end

@implementation

-(NSArray *) deepCopy
{
    NSMutableArray *ret = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (id val in self)
    {
        if ([val conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSCopying)])
        { 
            [ret addObject:[val copy]];
        }
        else
        {
           [ret addObject:val];
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

@end
```

Second of all, `newArray = oldArray` **does not copy the array**. It simply makes `newArray` point to the array that `oldArray` points to.

Third, `+arrayWithArray:` does a shallow copy of the array, meaning the individual objects are NOT copied.

Comment: I think you forgot the else around `[ret addObject:val];`

Comment: I think `[ret addObject:[val copy]]` is a memory leak assuming `NSCopying` is adopted according to Apple's docs (`copyWithZone:` returns an object that's implicitly retained by the sender).

Comment: Would assume ARC (automatic reference counting) is being used in this case.

Comment: [ret addObject:[val copy]]; will copy each element in original array shallow. then if I have an array of arrays using your method (deepcopy) I will end up with a new array with inner arrays shallow copied.which is wrong isn't it.

Comment: @عليامين no, it isn't "wrong", it's an edge case. If the copy implementation by a custom object doesn't do a deep copy (like it should, there's very little I can do, aside from serializing and deserializing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also call `[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:arraytoBeCopied copyItems:YES];`

Answer (score -8):

In Objective-C "Copy" keyword just increase the "Retain Count" of the object. So only use of "Copy" will not perform a copy.

But when we make a change in object, then Objective-C create a copy of the original object at that time.

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct.  In fact, I'm reasonably certain it's not.

Comment: You can find it in apple documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Really?  Because when I look at the documentation, I find that NSObject says that copy is a shortcut for copyWithZone:, which must be implemented by subclasses that wish to enable that function according to the NSCopying protocol.  Which specifies that CopyWithZone creates a new object with identical properties -- not an increase in retain count.  Furthermore, Apple has explicitly disabled all use of retain count since ARC was added.  So saying 'copy' just increases retain count on an object is flat-out wrong, no matter how you cut it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010162-SW3

Comment: I'm sorry didn't state my position more clearly:  I am NOT arguing with your second paragraph.  That, as far as I can tell, is correct (though as the documentation you link to points out, it doesn't produce a 'true' deep copy, because it will only go one level deep -- IMO, a flaw).  I am arguing *very* specifically with your first paragraph.  'Copy' does, in fact, return a new instance of the class.  It's just that the contents of that class are references to the old objects, rather than copies.