# NSCopying and Objective-C memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, autorelease, nscopying

Apple's NSCopying [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCopying) state that `copyWithZone:` returns an object that's implicitly retained by the sender. So when that object is added to an `NSMutableArray` it seems like the object should be sent an `autorelease` message to keep the retain count balanced (since the array will retain the object).

So to deep copy the contents of one array to another I'd expect something like:

```
NSMutableArray *destination = [NSMutableArray array];

// assume MyObject adopts NSCopying
for (MyObject *obj in myArray) 
    [destination addObject:[[obj copy] autorelease]];
```

However I noticed a different approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9912913/879664). It seems like `[ret addObject:[val copy]]` is a memory leak. However I'm brand new to `NSCopying` so I thought I'd ask: **When adding a copied object to an array should the object be sent an autorelease message to keep the retain count balanced?**

**Edit - more info**: Clang reports a potential memory leak after removing the autorelease. Perhaps the linked answer assumes `copy` returns an object that's *not* implicitly retained by the sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does need to be released but I wouldn't use `autorelease` in a loop like that, do it manually with each iteration

```
   for (MyObject *obj in myArray)
    {
        MyObject *copy = [obj copy];
        [destination addObject:copy];
        [copy release];
    }
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Is using `autorelease` incorrect? Or will it just incur a performance hit?

Comment: The copies are retained anyway by the array so not much different performance-wise in this case. But it's a good habit to explicitly release when you can, especially in tight loops - cleaner code too.