# How the memory will be managed after doing shallow copy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, copy

I was trying to understand memory management concept, and start digging from Apple docs and many articles regarding Memory management in Objective-C. When I start searching from Apple docs I was send back to object copying and messaging concept.

While reading about copying object I hit one question and I was trying to find the solution but fail to get satisfactory solution.
It will be honor if someone will help me out.
Question is:

```
 array1 = {obj1,obj2,obj3}
 array2 = {obj4,obj5,obj6}
 array2 = array1 -- Shallow Copy
```

**What happened to the memory which was associated with array2? How to release if there is a leak? What is better practice to perform such shallow copy in ARC and NonARC environment?**

Comment: if you perform this operation then in Objective-C compiler will simply save memory pointer of array1 in variable to access array1 objects... because objective-C compiler never allocate memory to same type of object which have same values... instead of this it simply take a reference of this... so it will take reference of this array

Comment: `array2` now points to the same memory as `array1`. Under ARC, the reference count to the old `array2` object will be decremented. If there are no more strong references to the old `array2` it will be `dealloc`ed and the memory "released". Once the old `array2` is `dealloc`ed, the reference counts for `obj4`, `obj5` and `obj6` will be decremented. For each of `obj4`, `obj5` and `obj6`, if there are no more strong references to that object it will be `dealloc`ed and the memory "released". If you are worried about a leak then you can directly set any of `obj4`, `obj5` and `obj6` to `nil`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep Copy and Shallow Copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912794/deep-copy-and-shallow-copy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign `array2 = array1` you are actually assigning an array reference, you are not copying anything, shallow or otherwise.

The array that was referenced  `array2` will be released if there is no other strong reference to this array.  As a result of the array being released, the objects in the array (`obj4`, `obj5` & `obj6`) will be released if there is no other variable holding a strong reference to any of them

So, initially you have

```
array1 = {obj1,obj2,obj3}
array2 = {obj4,obj5,obj6}
```

After the assignment you have

```
array1      array2
  \\         //
 {obj1,obj2,obj3}
```

and objects 4-6 have been released along with the array that held them