# ES6 React - What are the difference between reference, shallow copy and deep copy and how to compare them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I know this question has been discussed so many times, and I think I got a basic idea. There are some top rated answers I found from StackOverflow:

- [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)
- [Deep Copy and Shallow Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912794/deep-copy-and-shallow-copy)

But all the answers seems very fuzzy to me.
Let's consider the example below:

```js
const user = {
  name: "James",
  age: 33,
  highlights: {
    career: "Basketball player",
    NBAChampion: [2012, 2013, 2016],
  },
  promotion: () => ("Get LeBron15 now!"),
};

const james = user;
const clone = { ...user };
const clone2 = Object.assign({}, user);
const clone3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
const clone4 = {
  ...user,
  highlights: {
    ...user.highlights,
    // I comment the it out, so now NBAChampion is a reference rather than copy!
    // NBAChampion: [...user.highlights.NBAChampion]
  }
};

user.age++;
user.highlights.career = "football player";

console.log('james', james, james === user, james == user);
console.log('clone', clone, clone === user, clone == user);
console.log('clone2', clone2, clone2 === user, clone2 == user);
console.log('clone3', clone3, clone3 === user, clone3 == user);
// console.log(clone3.promotion()); // My problem with clone3 is that function's been removed. 
console.log('clone4', clone4, clone4 === user, clone4 == user);
```

- `james` is a reference, it's always exactly same as user;
- `clone` is a copy. **Is it a shallow copy or deep copy?** The `name` and `age` are separated from `user`, but the `highlights` is still a reference.
- `clone2` behaves exactly the same as `clone`.
- `clone3` is converted from a string. **Is it a deep copy?** It is not a perfect clone, since functions (*if there's any*) are not save to convert this way.
- `clone4` is copied every layer of `user`, so I can call it a "deep copy".
  However if the *spread operator* only creates deep copy **sometimes**, then **how can I test if the new object is a deep copy or not?**

**Update**: I commented `NBAChampion` out in `clone4`, so now NBAChampion is a reference rather than copy! If I push a new value in `user.highlights.NBAChampion`, `clone4` will also updates.
**What should we call this type of object?** It's neither a shallow nor deep copy.

---

### Why does this matter?

**React** has a `shouldComponentUpdate()` function which compares shallow copy. There is the [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).
In React [source code (Line: 356)](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/8e5f12ca6c18fb48ea71cba6bfa9bd7cf499ccb6/packages/react-reconciler/src/__tests__/ReactIncrementalSideEffects-test.internal.js), the **shallow comparison** is done like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  return this.props.children !== nextProps.children;
}
```

In the code demo above, the 2nd and 3rd parameters in `console.log` show the comparison results between `clone` and `user`. However, only 1st copy returns `true`. (*Note: there is no different between strict comparison and abstract comparison*)

If I apply `shouldComponentUpdate` to the demo above, obviously only `james` and `user` will return `true`. So `james` is a shallow copy in Facebook's code. Then my questions are:

- *Are reference and shallow copy exactly the same thing in JS? If not, why React do this?*
- *How can I test a object is a shallow copy or deep copy in my test case?*

The question took me lots of time to craft. Any clear explanation with example is welcome.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `clone` is a shallow copy. The primitive (and immutable) values of "name" and "age" are copies, yes, but then so is the reference to the "highlights" object; it's a copy of the reference.

Comment: "Are reference and shallow copy exactly the same thing in JS? If not, why React do this?" - references and shallow copies are certainly not the same thing. What exactly about React's shallow comparison do you find unintuitive? Also, james is not a shallow copy of user. And the link to React's source code seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's consider the example below

`clone` and `clone2` are shallow, only properties of original object are affected. `clone3` and `clone4` are deep.

> However if the spread operator only creates deep copy sometimes, then how can I test if the new object is a deep copy or not?

It creates deep copy in case of `clone4` - as long as the depth is controlled by a developer. Generally there's no need to test if an object is deep copy or just different in React, because this check is expensive and requires to traverse nested objects in both compared objects and compare them property by property.

Performance is the reason why React relies on immutability. If a new value isn't `===` equal, it's considered a different value.

> So james is a shallow copy in Facebook's code.

It isn't. It's a reference that was assigned to another variable. It's still same object.

> Are reference and shallow copy exactly the same thing in JS?

A reference isn't a copy. So it isn't shallow copy, too.

> I commented NBAChampion out in clone4, so now NBAChampion is a reference rather than copy! If I push a new value in user.highlights.NBAChampion, clone4 will also updates.
>   What should we call this type of object? It's neither a shallow nor deep copy.

It's just a copy. It doesn't have specific name, because there's rarely a need to do such selective copies. If the intention is to make it act like deep copy, it should be called a mistake.

Comment: *as long as the depth is controlled by a developer (as in clone4)*. The OP created a shallow copy at each level of nesting and ended up with deep copy.

Comment: OK well yes. Honestly I haven't figured out exactly what the sticking point the OP has over the concepts, because they're not that complicated once you "get it". I don't intend to demean, I just don't know what the crux of the matter is here.

Answer (score 1):

A *shallow copy* of an object (or array) is a separate object with a matching set of property names and property values.

After making a shallow copy, a comparison on a property-by-property basis of the two objects (the original and the copy) will show all property values being `===`.

For example:

```
let o1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: { x: "hello", y: "world" } };
let o2 = {};
Object.keys(o1).forEach(propertyName => o2[propertyName] = o1[propertyName]);
```

Now if the property values of o1 and o2 are compared, they are of course `===`. In particular, property "c" of both objects will be a reference to that sub-object with "x" and "y" property names. However, comparing `o1` and `o2` with either `==` or `===` will *not* show equality, because two distinct objects are never `==` to each other regardless of their contents.

A *deep copy* of an object is one where every object-valued property of the source is recursively deep-copied into the destination copy. Because new object values are of necessity created for the deep-copy target, those property values will *not* compare as `===`, because no two distinct objects can be `===`.

Making deep copies in a language like JavaScript can be problematic because the "graph" of references from property values can be circular, and because some property values may be functions. Generally a deep copy method has to make some assumptions on an application by application basis.

In my experience, the need to make a deep copy of an object is quite rare compared to making shallow copies.

Now, all that aside, comparison between two object *references* as in your bit of React code:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  return this.props.children !== nextProps.children;
}
```

has nothing to do with shallow or deep copies. That's a single comparison between two object properties, both named "children". The objects referenced by `this.props` and `nextProps` may be different objects or they may be the same object, and one may be a shallow or deep copy of the other, but that makes no difference for that comparison statement: all that's doing is comparing the two particular "children" property values for strict inequality. (It's true that if `nextProps` *happens* to be a shallow copy of `this.props`, or vice-versa, that `!==` comparison would be false, but the comparison doesn't have to know about the prior history of the two objects; it's just a single comparison of two values.)

Comment: As you said, `const clone4 = {...user, highlights: {...user.highlights}};` will return `false` if only compare the properties in 1st layer, but it's not a deep copy either. What is it then?  `james` and `clone` both will return `true`, then how can I ensure there is no side-effect during testing?

Comment: @FisNaN that is a deep copy. Why would you think it isn't? It's a weird thing to do because you create two separate values for "highlights", one a reference copy and one a new object shallow-copied from the source. *edit* well it's a *partial* deep copy I guess, if other properties of `user` are object references.

Comment: The nested `NBAChampion` is still a reference, so it will change when `user.highlights.NBAChampion` changes. This kind nested json is very common in real application, which makes the code extremely hard to test.

Comment: @FisNaN well yes, that's certainly something to keep track of in object reference languages like JavaScript. *edit* wait, no, the two "NBAChampion" values are separate arrays; adding or removing elements from one will not affect the other.

Comment: What should we call this kind object? deep or shallow or neither? If I wrote a function to compare shallow copies, it will return `false`, but it's also not safe to changes.

Comment: @FisNaN if you're talking about `NBAChampion` inside of `clone4` then no, it won't change when `user.highlights.NBAChampion` changes. It's a shallow copy, but since all values inside of `NBAChampion` are numbers, there's no connection whatsoever between those two arrays.

Comment: I've never felt the need for terminology like that, and it's really really rare that I feel the need to make deep copies; it just doesn't come up that often (almost never in fact).

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev `const clone = {...user, highlights: {...user.highlights}};`  this is a grey area which get people really confused.

Comment: @FisNaN that assignment is equivalent two the *two* assignments `const clone = { ... user }; clone.highlights = { ... user.highlights };` A shallow copy followed by another shallow copy.