# How to declare array of pointers in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays

I dont know how to declare a array which just stores pointers to objects. As per My understanding ,if I use method

```
    [ someArray addObject:someObject ] ,
```

It would then add the copy of object to array and any changes to object wont get reflected to original object.

What I want is that create a array of pointers which would just point to objects and changes made to objects would persist. pardon me, If I am missing something basic.

Comment: It would then add the copy of object to array and any changes to object wont get reflected to original object. - incorrect see answer you should have accepted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` *is* an array of pointers.  No copying is done.

Answer (score 2):

you have your basics wrong. technically when you do that you create the array of pointers to those objects.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html read the description.

If you want to get the object copied you have to explicitly say so.

Look at this question for example

[Deep copying an NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647260/deep-copy-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c)

By the way you should use an NSMutableArray.

Also look at the superclass NSArray

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray

specifically for the **initWithArray:copyItems:**

> flag
>
> If YES, each object in array receives a copyWithZone: message to
>   create a copy of the object—objects must conform to the NSCopying
>   protocol. In a managed memory environment, this is instead of the
>   retain message the object would otherwise receive. The object copy is
>   then added to the returned array.
>
> If NO, then in a managed memory environment each object in array simply receives a retain message when it is added to the returned
>   array.

By default adding an object to a nsmutablearray increases its capacity if necessary, adds a retain for the object, and the pointer to the object.

Answer (score 2):

> ...if I use method
>
> ```
> [ someArray addObject:someObject ] ,
> ```
>
> It would then add the copy of object to array and any changes to
>   object wont get reflected to original object.

While it technically doesn't pertain to the question, I simply must correct your terminology.  "Copy" in Objective-C implies that the method `-copy` is sent to the object, which would create a new object in of itself.  What Arrays do is send `-retain` to their objects, which means that the array itself now owns a stake in the object, which is why changes that don't reference the array (`-objectAtIndex:`), or have a valid claim to the object itself are not reflected.

> What I want is that create a array of pointers which would just point
>   to objects and changes made to objects would persist. pardon me, If I
>   am missing something basic.

Well, unfortunately iOS does not support the class [NSPointerArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html), which would make your life significantly easy in regards to an actual array of pointers.  Without getting into any C-craziness, I can only reiterate what I mentioned above:  If you need to mutate an object in an array, just access it with a valid reference to it, or use `-objectAtIndex`.  So long as you still have a valid claim on the object (a reference in this case, it's pointer didn't change because it was sent `-retain`) you can change it.  Note the simple example below:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Hello"];
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:str, nil];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
[str appendString:@" Friend!"];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

This prints:

```
2012-08-07 21:37:46.368 .MyApp[2325:303] (
    Hello
)
2012-08-07 21:37:46.369 .MyApp[2325:303] (
    "Hello Friend!"
)
```

Simple!

Comment: Why would NSPointerArray be useful for what the OP is asking?

Comment: the array is an actual array of pointers. the difference to the class you mention is NSPointerArray is a mutable collection modeled after NSArray but it can also hold NULL values, which can be inserted or extracted (and which contribute to the object’s count). https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @CodaFi, I think the behavior the OP is looking for **is** the behavior of a normal NSMutableArray.

Comment: Yes, exactly, which is why I included the example.  Perhaps I'm being a bit too literal...