# How to copy all objects of NSArray when copying the array itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nscopying

I have an array of objects

I want to copy the array and all contents of it

"Object" implements NSCopying

I thought that doing

```
NSArray *copiedArray = [array copy];
```

would trigger copyWithZone in the objects contained inside of it.

Unfortunally not...

How can this be done?

Comment: You want a deep copy of the array?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya and whoever upvoted you: That's a shallow copy, the question is about creating a deep copy.

Comment: @JustSid: I cant find he asked for deep or shallow?

Comment: If you want a deep copy then JustSid answer is good. For more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647260/deep-copy-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c

Comment: @AnoopVaidya He says that he thought that `copy` would call `copyWithZone:` on all objects in the container, unfortunately it doesn't. It ends with `How can this be done?`. Granted, it doesn't mention deep copies explicitly, but that's what he is asking...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on how deep you want the copy of the array to be. If one level is enough, [`- initWithArray:copyItems:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithArray%3acopyItems%3a) is going to do the trick. If you want an actual deep copy, you have to write it yourself I'm afraid.