# How can I easily duplicate/copy an existing realm object

Tags: swift, realm

I have a Realm Object which has several relationships, anyone has a good code snippet that generalizes a copy method, to create a duplicate in the database.

Answer (score 38):

In my case i just wanted to create an object and not persist it. so `segiddins`'s solution didn't work for me.

**Swift 3**

To create a clone of user object in `swift` just use

`let newUser = User(value: oldUser)`;

The new user object is not persisted.

Comment: Please note that the resulting `newUser` object is a *shallow copy* of the original! If it contains nested references to other Realm objects, those will be referenced in the new object - *NOT copied*! A very important side effect of that, is that you might experience threading issues when you try to access those nested objects. Also related: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3381

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following to create a shallow copy of your object, as long as it does not have a primary key:

```
realm.create(ObjectType.self, withValue: existingObject)
```

Comment: In my case there is a primary key, I will file a feature request on github for it then.

Comment: Idea: is there a way to detach an object (and its relationships) from a Realm then replace the primary keys in the object (and its relationships)  and then add it again?

Comment: There's currently no way to do that built-in to realm, but you can do a recursive copy manually. Be sure to link me to the issue you've filed!

Comment: @segiddins see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144657/how-can-i-easily-duplicate-copy-an-existing-realm-object/67887043#67887043

Answer (score 5):

As of now, Dec 2020, there is no proper solution for this issue. We have many workarounds though.

Here is the one I have been using, and one with less limitations in my opinion.

1. Make your Realm Model Object classes conform to codable

```
class Dog: Object, Codable{
    @objc dynamic var breed:String = "JustAnyDog"
}
```

2. Create this helper class

```
class RealmHelper {
    //Used to expose generic 
    static func DetachedCopy<T:Codable>(of object:T) -> T?{
       do{
           let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(object)
           return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: json)
       }
       catch let error{
           print(error)
           return nil
       }
    }
}
```

3. Call this method whenever you need **detached / true deep copy** of your Realm Object, like this:

```
 //Suppose your Realm managed object: let dog:Dog = RealmDBService.shared.getFirstDog()
 guard let detachedDog = RealmHelper.DetachedCopy(of: dog) else{
    print("Could not detach Dog")
    return
 }
//Change/mutate object properties as you want
 detachedDog.breed = "rottweiler"
```

As you can see we are piggy backing on Swift's JSONEncoder and JSONDecoder, using power of Codable, making true deep copy no matter how many nested objects are there under our realm object. Just make sure all your Realm Model Classes conform to Codable.

Though its **NOT** an ideal solution, but its one of the most effective workaround.

Comment: Having an "Only unmanaged Realm objects can be encoded using automatic Codable synthesis" issue with this approach.

Comment: Can you share more details? Unable to figure out what you meant.

Comment: when using DetachedCopy with a managed object. Realm complains an error says only unmanaged realm object can be encoded.

Comment: @Xinyang can you share a code snippet? Also just confirming, you explicitly conformed to Codable protocol in you realm models right?

Comment: this method can't work unless you also implement the `encode(to: )` method which beats the purpose of the solution

Comment: @RaduUrsache you don't have to. Conforming to the codable will auto generate(compiler) encode method, unless there some custom/generic stuff going on in your model.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and found a simple workaround to get a copy of a realm object. Basically you just need to make the object conform to the NSCopying protocol, something like:

```
import RealmSwift
import Realm
import ObjectMapper

class Original: Object, NSCopying{
   dynamic var originalId = 0
   dynamic var firstName = ""
   dynamic var lastName = ""

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "originalId"
}

init(originalId: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String){
    super.init()

    self.originalId = originalId
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
}

func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
    let copy = Original(originalId: originalId, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName)

    return copy
}
}
```

then you just call the "copy()" method on the object:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var original = Original()
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       var myCopy = original.copy()
   }
}
```

The nice thing about having a copy is that I can modify it without having to be in a realm write transaction. Useful when users are editing some data but didn't hit save yet or simply changed their mind.

Answer (score 1):

Since this problem is still alive I post my solution which works but still needs to be improved.
I've created an extension of Object class that has this method duplicate that takes an object `objOut` and fills the flat properties by looking at self. When a non-flat property is found (aka a nested object) that one is skipped.

```
// Duplicate object with its flat properties
func duplicate(objOut: Object) -> Object {

    // Mirror object type
    let objectType: Mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self);

    // Iterate on object properties
    for child in objectType.children {

        // Get label
        let label = child.label!

        // Handler for flat properties, skip complex objects
        switch String(describing: type(of: child.value)) {
        case "Double", "Int", "Int64", "String":
            objOut.setValue(self.value(forKey: label)!, forKey: label)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    return objOut
}
```

Inside the Manager class for my Realms I have the method `copyFromRealm()` that I use to create my copies of objects.
To give you a practical example this is the structure of my Appointment class:

```
Appointment object
    - flat properties
    - one UpdateInfo object
        - flat properties
    - one AddressLocation object
        - flat properties
        - one Address object
            - flat properties
        - one Coordinates object
            - flat properies
    - a list of ExtraInfo
        - each ExtraInfo object
            - flat properties
```

This is how I've implemented the copyFromRealm() method:

```
// Creates copy out of realm
func copyFromRealm() -> Appointment {

    // Duplicate base object properties
    let cpAppointment = self.duplicate(objOut: Appointment()) as! Appointment

    // Duplicate UIU object
    cpAppointment.uiu = self.uiu?.duplicate(objOut: UpdateInfo()) as? UpdateInfo

    // Duplicate AddressLocation object
    let cpAddress = self.addressLocation?.address?.duplicate(objOut: Address()) as? Address
    let cpCoordinates = self.addressLocation?.coordinates?.duplicate(objOut: Coordinates()) as? Coordinates
    cpAppointment.addressLocation = self.addressLocation?.duplicate(objOut: AddressLocation()) as? AddressLocation
    cpAppointment.addressLocation?.address = cpAddress
    cpAppointment.addressLocation?.coordinates = cpCoordinates

    // Duplicate each ExtraInfo
    for other in self.others {
        cpAppointment.others.append(other.duplicate(objOut: ExtraInfo()) as! ExtraInfo)
    }

    return cpAppointment
}
```

I wasn't able to find out a good and reasonable way to work with nested objects inside my duplicate() method. I thought of recursion but code complexity raised too much.

This is not optimal but works, if I'll find a way to manage also nested object I'll update this answer.

Comment: Good answer, with least amount work needed for my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5+

Creates a Realm managed copy of an existing Realm managed object with ID

```
extension RLMObject {
    
    func createManagedCopy(withID newID: String) -> RLMObject? {
        
        let realmClass = type(of: self)
        guard let realm = self.realm, let primaryKey = realmClass.primaryKey() else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let shallowCopy = realmClass.init(value: self)
        shallowCopy.setValue(newID, forKey: primaryKey)
        
        do {
            realm.beginWriteTransaction()
            realm.add(shallowCopy)
            try realm.commitWriteTransaction()
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
        
        return shallowCopy
        
    }
    
}
```