# how to make a deep copy of a swift array of class objects

Tags: ios, swift

So I know that swift array is implemented as struct, and it will do automatically copy by itself.

I have write my class `MyClass` and I have implemented `copyWithZone` to make copy of it

However, my swift array contains my `MyClass` objects, like:

`var array = [MyClass]()`

when I wan to make a copy of that array like

`var anotherArray = array`

It still does not call `MyClassObject.copyWithZone`, and later if I change the object property in `array`, `anotherArray` will also reflect the change.

How can I make a copy of that *without* writing a for loop to iterate every object?

It's not duplicated as [deep copy for array of objects in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357060/deep-copy-for-array-of-objects-in-swift) because I cannot use struct to rewrite my class.

Comment: No it's not, the answer is saying I have to use struct to automatically copy. However I cannot change it to struct. It's a big class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'll cancel my close vote

Comment: You might want to consider adding an extension to Array.  Read the question and the first answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027116/how-can-i-extend-typed-arrays-in-swift  However, you can't avoid using an explicit or an implicit loop.

Comment: thanks! I will consider a extension

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a simple statement, you could use code like this:

```
var copiedArray = array.map{$0.copy()}
```

Note that the term "deepCopy" is a little misleading for what you're talking about. What if the array is heterogeneous and contains other containers like arrays, dictionaries, sets, and other custom container and "leaf" objects? What you should really do is to create a protocol DeepCopiable and make it a requirement that any object that conforms to DeepCopiable require that any child objects also conform to the DeepCopiable protocol, and write the deepCopy() method to recursively call deepCopy() on all child objects. That way you wind up with a deep copy that works at any arbitrary depth.

Comment: this is less words than a for loop, which is great; however, why swift array cannot directly to do so? It should know it contains class object and call copy()...

Comment: Because that's not how it works. Copy is a shallow copy. Usually that's what you want. Deep copying is MUCH more expensive, both in terms of memory and time.

Comment: So the conclusion is looping every object is the only solution?

Comment: A deep copy involves making a duplicate of every object in the array. On some level, you must iterate through the members and duplicate them. Even if Swift arrays had a deepCopy method, that method would internally need to iterate through the array's contents and duplicate them. The map statement gives you what you want without having to write a loop.

Answer (score 5):

If Element of an array is of reference type, conform that Element with NSCopying and implement `copyWithZone` method.

```
class Book {
    var name: String

    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name  = name
    }
}

extension Book: NSCopying {
    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        return Book(name)
    }
}
```

Now implement an  array extension to make a deep copy

```
extension Array where Element: NSCopying {
      func copy() -> [Element] {
            return self.map { $0.copy() as! Element }
      }
}
```

Test the code base

```
let b1 = Book("Book1")
let b2 = Book("Book2")

let list = [b1, b2]
let clonedList = list.copy()
```

`clonedList` is now copy  of `list` and won't affect each-other if you make change to any of two.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Duncan for your solution, here is an extension using it.
Note that your class must adopt the NSCopying protocol. For how to do that see here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-copy-objects-in-swift-using-copy

```
extension Array {
    func copiedElements() -> Array<Element> {
        return self.map{
            let copiable = $0 as! NSCopying
            return copiable.copy() as! Element
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the term "deepCopy" is a little misleading. What if the array is heterogeneous and contains other containers like arrays, dictionaries, sets, and other custom container and "leaf" objects? What you should really do is to create a protocol `DeepCopiable` and make it a requirement that any object that conforms to  `DeepCopiable` require that any child objects also conform to the  `DeepCopiable` protocol, and write the `deepCopy()` method to recursively call `deepCopy()` on all child objects. That way you wind up with a deep copy that works at any arbitrary depth.

Comment: Great point. I'm going to rename the function from `deepCopy()` to `copiedElements()` to avoid confusion.