# How to make a copy of a swift array of class objects

Tags: arrays, swift, deep-copy

In code below, list1 is original Array.
when i copy list1 in list2, it passes "allCardList" array as reference but i want to create copy of list1 so when i change in list2 it shouldn't change original Array (list1)

```
class Card {
    var availableBalance        = "5"
}
class DataCacheManager: NSObject {
    var allCardList             = [Card]()
}
var card = Card()
card.availableBalance = "10"

var list1 = DataCacheManager()
list1.allCardList.append(card)

var list2 = DataCacheManager()

for item in list1.allCardList {
    list2.allCardList.append(item)
}

list2.allCardList[0].availableBalance = "20"

print(list1.allCardList[0].availableBalance) // print 20 but should return 10
```

Any help you that?

Comment: Of course it will print 20 since you are changing the reference object. You need to deep copy you array if you want to have different values.

Comment: How can i have deep copy?

Answer (score 2):

A `class` has reference semantics. The simplest solution is to use value semantics

```
struct Card ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question, it describes the process of copying a single object.

[Implementing copy() in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242629/implementing-copy-in-swift)

After you added the ability of copying, iterate through your array with a `for` loop to create a copied array from your existing data.

Answer (score 0):

Please read these references
[How do I make a exact duplicate copy of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812433/how-do-i-make-a-exact-duplicate-copy-of-an-array])[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357060/deep-copy-for-array-of-objects-in-swift)
and [deep copy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357060/deep-copy-for-array-of-objects-in-swift) In you case there other ways to achive your requirement without copying the whole array. For a example you could have an readonly original value as a object in Card and have another variable for the new value and so on.