# RealmSwift: Detach an object from Realm, including its properties of List type

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to create a duplicate of a persisted object such that the new instance has all the same values but is not attached to Realm. Using `Object(value: persistedInstance)` works great for classes whose properties are all strings, dates, numbers, etc. However, when duplicating an instance of a class with List type properties, the duplicate's List and the List's elements continue to reference the persisted records. How can I create a duplicate that's fully detached from Realm, including any Lists and elements in those Lists?

Comment: Have you tried using `Results.flatMap { $0 }.first`? I usually use `map` and `flatMap` to get 'frozen' Realm objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not yet supported natively by Realm, but a [requested feature tracked by issue #3381](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3381).

For now, you would need to implement your own deep copy constructor. A common strategy is to do that on every model and call the deep copy constructors of related objects. You need to pay attention though that you don't run into cycles.

Answer (score 20):

You can make a deep copy of your object via the following extension functions:

```
    import UIKit
    import Realm
    import RealmSwift
    
    protocol RealmListDetachable {

    func detached() -> Self
}

extension List: RealmListDetachable where Element: Object {

    func detached() -> List<Element> {
        let detached = self.detached
        let result = List<Element>()
        result.append(objectsIn: detached)
        return result
    }

}

@objc extension Object {

    public func detached() -> Self {
        let detached = type(of: self).init()
        for property in objectSchema.properties {
            guard
                property != objectSchema.primaryKeyProperty,
                let value = value(forKey: property.name)
            else { continue }
            if let detachable = value as? Object {
                detached.setValue(detachable.detached(), forKey: property.name)
            } else if let list = value as? RealmListDetachable {
                detached.setValue(list.detached(), forKey: property.name)
            } else {
                detached.setValue(value, forKey: property.name)
            }
        }
        return detached
    }
}

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Object {

    public var detached: [Element] {
        return self.map({ $0.detached() })
    }

}
```

Use

```
/// in collections
let data = realm.objects(AbcDfg.self).detached

/// single object
data.first?.detached()
```

Comment: You are a god among men.You solution saved me ton of time

Comment: @user578386 I'm glad I could help you out.

Comment: This, unfortunately, doesn't copy internal variables.
F.e: `var myVar: Bool = false`
after calling `.detached()` this variable will have default value false, even you've changed it. 
Sometimes you might need runtime variables.

Comment: @CarlosChaguendo <T> T in List extension is throwing error, do you have any idea in this? I am using Xcode 11

Comment: @jegadeesh change `T` with `Element`

Comment: @CarlosChaguendo I tried that already. Getting "Argument type '() -> List<Element>' does not conform to expected type 'RealmCollectionValue" error from compiler for that. Didn't know how to solve that, any idea?

Comment: @jegadeesh I just updated the code to the new versions of realm.

Comment: @CarlosChaguendo Thank you! Will try this out.

Comment: Hi @CarlosChaguendo, why did you guard the `objectSchema.primaryKeyProperty `

Comment: Will this code deep copy all the nested variables as well?

Answer (score 3):

We use ObjectMapper to create a deep copy of the object by turning into JSON and then turn that JSON back into same object except it's not associated with Realm.

Mike.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the issue tracked at [#3381](http://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3381), the solution for now is an implementation to create detached copies from Realm objects. 
There is a better version of the detachable object implementation at 
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5433#issuecomment-415066361.

Incase the link doesnot work, the code by Alarson93 is:

```
protocol DetachableObject: AnyObject {
    func detached() -> Self
}

extension Object: DetachableObject {

    func detached() -> Self {
        let detached = type(of: self).init()
        for property in objectSchema.properties {
            guard let value = value(forKey: property.name) else { continue }

            if property.isArray == true {
                //Realm List property support
                let detachable = value as? DetachableObject
                detached.setValue(detachable?.detached(), forKey: property.name)
            } else if property.type == .object {
                //Realm Object property support
                let detachable = value as? DetachableObject
                detached.setValue(detachable?.detached(), forKey: property.name)
            } else {
                detached.setValue(value, forKey: property.name)
            }
        }
        return detached
    }
}

extension List: DetachableObject {
    func detached() -> List<Element> {
        let result = List<Element>()

        forEach {
            if let detachable = $0 as? DetachableObject {
                let detached = detachable.detached() as! Element
                result.append(detached)
            } else {
                result.append($0) //Primtives are pass by value; don't need to recreate
            }
        }

        return result
    }

    func toArray() -> [Element] {
        return Array(self.detached())
    }
}

extension Results {
    func toArray() -> [Element] {
        let result = List<Element>()

        forEach {
            result.append($0)
        }

        return Array(result.detached())
    }
}
```

Comment: It is getting into infinite loop!

Answer (score 3):

In Realm 5.0.0 `freeze()` method has been added.
according to release notes:

> Add support for frozen objects. Realm, Results, List and Object now have freeze() methods which return a frozen copy of the object. These objects behave similarly to creating unmanaged deep copies of the source objects. They can be read from any thread and do not update when writes are made to the Realm, but creating frozen objects does not actually copy data out of the Realm and so can be much faster and use less memory. Frozen objects cannot be mutated or observed for changes (as they never change). (PR #6427).

Answer (score 2):

Previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65436546/6709940)

As of now, Dec 2020, there is not proper solution of this issue. We have many workarounds though.

Here is the one I have been using, and one with less limitations in my opinion.

1. Make your Realm Model Object classes conform to codable

```
class Dog: Object, Codable{
    @objc dynamic var breed:String = "JustAnyDog"
}
```

2. Create this helper class

```
class RealmHelper {
    //Used to expose generic 
    static func DetachedCopy<T:Codable>(of object:T) -> T?{
       do{
           let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(object)
           return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: json)
       }
       catch let error{
           print(error)
           return nil
       }
    }
}
```

3. Call this method whenever you need **detached / true deep copy** of your Realm Object, like this:

```
 //Suppose your Realm managed object: let dog:Dog = RealmDBService.shared.getFirstDog()
 guard let detachedDog = RealmHelper.DetachedCopy(of: dog) else{
    print("Could not detach Dog")
    return
 }
//Change/mutate object properties as you want
 detachedDog.breed = "rottweiler"
```

As you can see we are piggy backing on Swift's JSONEncoder and JSONDecoder, using power of Codable, making true deep copy no matter how many nested objects are there under our realm object. Just make sure all your Realm Model Classes conform to Codable.

Though its **NOT** an ideal solution, but its one of the most effective workaround.