# How to clone an object like Java in swift

Tags: swift

```
class Person implements Cloneable {
    int age;
    Person(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        try {
            return super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p = new Person(0);
    Person p1 = (Person) p.clone();
    p.age = 10;
    System.out.println(p.age + " " + p1.age);

}
```

the result is 10 0
In java, we can simply use the super.clone() to implement the clone.
but how can I do the same thing in swift ?
must I write something like this to implement the clone in swift ?

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCopying {
     var age: Int?

    func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        var p = Person()
        p.age = self.age
        return p
    }
}
```

it seems ok with one class, one member. but if I has a lot of child class, and every child class has different members, it will be a lot of code, I should implement clone for every child class.

in java, only one clone method in superclass, it is much more simple.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754559/how-to-do-deep-copy-in-swift

Comment: thanks, I have seen this, it is not the answer I want.  @aadarshs

Comment: I guess the answer is that Swift lacks this comfort. No idea whether Swift2 brings any improvement here.

Answer (score 2):

In Obj-C, the correct way to copy objects is using the `NSCopying` protocol.
In Swift, you should typically use a copy constructor although you can use `NSCopying` for classes that are derived from `NSObject`.

Yes, you have to write more code, however, `clone` in Java is one of the worst OOP problems in Java. It is not designed well. The fact that it decides what is going to be copied for you is not a good thing.

Also see [How to properly override clone method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method)

In short, in Java, if you are implementing `clone`, you shouldn't call `Object.clone`. Implement the object creation using a constructor and decide by yourself what should be copied and how.

Comment: why clone in java is one of the worst OOP problems ? could you explain in detail please ?

Comment: @JIEWANG One of the most interesting problems is that it creates an object without invoking any constructors. The forced check for `Cloneable` is not nice either. There are many examples on the internet for `.clone` problems. Implementing `clone` using a private copy constructor is a nice idea. Of course, then you get exactly the same as is provided by `NSCopying`.

Comment: https://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm

@Sulthan  thanks, I have read this article, and .clone seems not too bad if there is no static or final attribute in the class.