# How to create a pointer in Swift?

Tags: swift, pointers, variables

I'm working with Swift 3.

I would like to have this C syntax :

```
int myVar;
int *pointer = &myVar;
```

So modifying `pointer` or `myVar` does the same exact same thing.
Also I don't know if it makes any difference, but in my case `myVar` is an array containing elements of a class and `pointer` is a pointer to one element of this array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do "Deep Copy" in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754559/how-to-do-deep-copy-in-swift)

Comment: Have you tried it?  In what way does `var selectedRow = rows[0]` not do what you want?  (From your description, it seems to me that you don't want a copy at all, just a shared pointer.)

Comment: It creates a copy of `rows[0]` but the two variables are different, when I modify `selectedRow` it doesn't affect `rows[0]` at all. And yes I want a shared pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming I understand what you're asking for....)

Try the following code in a playground.  It should print "99" three times.

```
class Row {
    var rowNumber = 0
}

var rows = [Row]()

let testRow = Row()
testRow.rowNumber = 1

rows.append(testRow)

let selectedRow = rows[0]
selectedRow.rowNumber = 99

print(testRow.rowNumber)
print(selectedRow.rowNumber)
print(rows[0].rowNumber)
```

By default, there's no copying of objects as part of an assignment statement.  If it were a struct, that would be different.

---

Adding a bit for completeness:

If you want a similar effect with scalar values instead of objects, Swift supplies various types of wrappers.

```
let intPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 8)  // Should be 1, not 8 according to comment re: docs
let other = intPointer
other.pointee = 34

print(intPointer.pointee)
```

(Warning: I haven't used these wrappers for anything except experimenting in a playground.  Don't trust it without doing some research.)

Comment: Okay, I'm missing something here. I thought my code didn't work because this syntax wasn't correct but I tried your code in a playground and it works fine, so my code works too, I must have something wrong elsewhere. Now why this works with a class but not with variables ? for example `var myVar = 5`, `var otherVar = myVar` and `otherVar = 5` doesn't change `myVar` value ?

Comment: The difference is that objects are referenced through pointers.  So, in my case, I have one actual object and three variables containing the one value that points to it.  In your `myVar` example, you're changing the actual variable contents; there's no independent object that they both reference.  (It would be the same as me typing `let selectedRow = Row()` and expecting its changes to be reflected in `testRow`.  People sometimes try that, but it never works.  :) )

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be `.allocate(capacity: 1)`. Doc for the parameter: _The amount of memory to allocate, counted in instances of `Pointee`._

Comment: Thanks @nyg.  It's definitely not something I've looked at for real use.

Answer (score 4):

The `&` also exists in Swift but can only be used as part of a parameter list (e.g. init, func, closure).

```
var i = 5
let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer(&i)
print(ptr.pointee) // 5

// or
let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)
ptr.initialize(to: 5)

// or with a closure
let ptr: UnsafePointer = { $0 }(&i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Same example as @Phillip. But I used struct. In this example rows[0] won't change:

```
struct Row {
    var rowNumber = 0
}

var rows = [Row]()

var testRow = Row()
testRow.rowNumber = 1

rows.append(testRow)

var selectedRow = rows[0]
selectedRow.rowNumber = 99

print(testRow.rowNumber) // prints 1
print(selectedRow.rowNumber) // prints 99
print(rows[0].rowNumber)  // prints 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no C style pointers  ([Unsafe Pointer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafepointer)) as the question asks however objects are shared by reference and structures are by value:

Swift `assign`, `pass` and `return` a value by reference for `reference type` and by copy for Value Type

`structures` are always copied when they are passed around in your code, but `classes` are passed by reference.

#### For example

##### How to have pointers/ references to objects

```
class Song {
    
    init(title: String, image: String, file: String, volume: Float, queuePlayer: AVQueuePlayer, playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?) {
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
        ...
    }
    var title: String
    var image: String
    ...
}

var aSong = Song(title: "", image: "", ...)

var arrOfSongReferences: [Song] = [Song]()
arrOfSongReferences.append(aSong)

var ptrToASong: Song = aSong

aSong = nil
// Due to Swift garbage collection ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), we still have references to the original aSong object so it won't be deleted
```

##### If data is struct you cannot do this

```
struct Song {
    var title: String
    var image: String
    ...
}

var aSong: Song = Song(title: "", image: "", ...)
var copyOfASong: Song = aSong
```

##### Method

You can also pass by reference into a function

```
// this would be inside a class, perhaps Player. It doesn't have to be a static btw
static func playSound(_ sound: inout Song, volume: Float = 0.0) {
        if (sound.playerLooper == nil) {
               ...
        }
}

// usage
Player.playSound(sound: &aSong)
```